# How to change Default login button in FBSDKLoginButton in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to Customize the Login button in Facebook?  I don't want to use Facebook default login button.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For SDK 4.0 :

U should add a button and in button action use the below code :

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonClicked:(id)sender {

   FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
   [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // Process error
            NSLog(@"error %@",error);                
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            // Handle cancellations
           NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        } else {
           if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                // Do work
                NSLog(@"%@",result);
                NSLog(@"Correct");
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

**Updated :** To receive Users Information

```
 - (IBAction)loginButtonClicked:(id)sender {

       FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
       [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // Process error
                NSLog(@"error %@",error);                
            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                // Handle cancellations
               NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            } else {
               if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                    // Do work
                     [self fetchUserInfo];
                }
            }
        }];
    }

-(void)fetchUserInfo {

    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {

    NSLog(@"Token is available");

    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"Fetched User Information:%@", result);

         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
         }
     }];

    } else {

        NSLog(@"User is not Logged in");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you worked exactly as i want.. and one more thing.. How can i show FBlogin view in Pop up? Can you suggest me? thanks in advance @dheeraj singh

Comment: do you want to show login button in a popup ? or the view while inserting credentials .

Comment: in above code the [result.grantedPermission ]is not returning anything.. email is null only

Comment: is it happening after you login or some else condition is called

Comment: after login in successfully .                                                                                if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]){
                // Do work
                NSLog(@"%@",result);
                NSLog(@"Correct");
            }                                                                                                                  i am not getting email of the facebook user in this condition  @dheeraj singh

Comment: @DeepakBradly updated the answer,go through it an let me know if it works

Comment: /*!
     @deprecated use logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler: instead
     
    - (void)logInWithReadPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions handler:(FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler)handler
    __attribute__ ((deprecated("use logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler: instead")));
   
    */
Thus made minor modification in above answer.

        [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `UIButton` and add a click method like this：

```
- (IBAction)fbLogin:(id)sender {
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *fbSession, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                      [self sessionStateChanged:fbSession state:state error:error];
                                  }];
}
```

Comment: FBSession does not exist in Facebook SDK 4.x

Answer (score 0):

```
FBLoginView *fbLoginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]];


fbLoginView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 271, 37);
 for (id obj in fbLoginView.subviews)
    {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton * loginButton =  obj;
            UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImg.png"];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [loginButton sizeToFit];
        }
}
```

Comment: FBLoginView is deprecated now that the FBSDKLoginKit is out there. Facebook strongly suggests that we use the latest SDK in order for it approve our app for AppStore

Answer (score 0):

I Just end up in iOS 9. put this code in button action method.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {


         // The session is open. Get the user information and update the UI.
         [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                      parameters:@{@"fields": @"first_name,last_name, email"}
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                   if (!error) {
                                       // Set the use full name.

                                       NSLog(@"FBresponse: =>%@",result);
                                   }
                                   else{
                                       NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                   }
                               }];



     }];
```