# Facebook Login for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I already have a Facebook Login Button, that works perfectly (upon pressing the button, I get to a login screen and upon successful login, I get back to the original page, where the FB Button now says "Log out" instead of "Log In"). However, I need a way to discern when a login was successful or not and obviously this does not work with a simple method, in which I check for button clicks. The reason I need to check for successful logins is that I need to set some tokens that are useful for user identification purposes. So how can I do that in Objective C?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "Custom Login Button" section on the following page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios

To check if the user is currently logged in or not

`if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
   // User is logged in, do work such as go to next view controller. 
  }`

Comment: I have that currently in viewDidLoad. However, I need a way to recognize successful logins after the button was pressed and login was successful. The issue is that the view is still the same.

Comment: when the facebook application gives control back to your application the following method in your viewcontroller would be executed:

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

you will have to implement <FBLoginViewDelegate>

Comment: that method is sadly not an option, as I am not using FBLoginView but FBSDKLoginButton

Comment: I have not used that but as per the following link completion handler is the way:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766317/how-to-change-default-login-button-in-fbsdkloginbutton-in-ios